# Archives for Model in python to appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, data-modeling

I'm a noob in python, and i'm creating a app into appengine with python.

I define class form Model's bug i don't know how order archives, normally, i create diferrent archives with all entities of my model, buy i don't know if in python is normal do the same think.

I think is normal define Model for all app in one file and then import it when you need, but i'm very noob in python and i can't find information about it.

And what it's the normal structure of files in python projects ?

Thx and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a "simple" project of google, with a example:

http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/#svn/trunk/overheard